# Python convert string date to YYYY/MM/DD date time object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to python problem is I have different formatted dates I want all to convert into yyyy/mm/dd format.

I have tried following:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
a = parser("19/04/2018")
finnal_date = a.strftime('%y/%m/%d')
```

working fine which is :- `18/04/19`

but when I am trying :-

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
a = parser("03/04/2018")
finnal_date = a.strftime('%y/%m/%d')
```

Output is :- `18/03/04`  which should be `18/04/03`

Comment: Need `a = parser("19/04/2018", dayfirst=True)`

Comment: Thanks brother !!

Comment: Glad can help! :) Nice day!